# Unitarily equivalent?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm confused about that notion.
In my textbook there are two examples.
(1) $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&0\\0&2&3\\0&0&3\end{pmatrix}$ and  $B=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&3\end{pmatrix}$
They have same eigenvalues but not unitarily equivalent because one is symmetric and the other is not.

(2)  $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0\\-1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and  $B=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&i&0\\0&0&-i\end{pmatrix}$
They have same eigenvalues and unitarily equivalent.

I can't understand.
The second one is the same form with the first one (I mean, one is symmetric and the other is not), but why it is unitarily equivalent?

Comment: I think you've a made a typo in your second $B$. Its eigenvalues should be $1,\,\pm i$

Comment: @TZakrevskiy You're right. I corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ and $B$ are unitarily equivalent $\iff$ $\exists\, U:\, U^{\ast}=U^{-1}$, $U^\ast A U=B$.

In the first case you always have $(U^\ast B U)^\ast = U^\ast B U$, while $A^\ast\ne A$, hence not unitarily equivalent to $B$.

But the same argument fails in the second case, because both matrices are asymmetric. When complex numbers come into play, you need to use adjoint matrices, not transposed.

So, in order to prove that in second case the matrices are unitarily equivalent, it's sufficient to find an orthonormal basis in $\mathbb C^3$ which consists of eigenvectors of the matrix $A$, which is quite easy to do.